# Elementary proof of Wright-Fisher's time until fixation formula?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Consider the Markov process $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\def\N{\mathbb{N}}\def\E{\text{E}}\newcommand{\bp}[1]{{\left({#1}\right)}}(X_t^n)_{t\in\Z_+}$ given by $X_0^n = p \in [0,1]$ and $X_{t+1}^n|X_t^n \sim \frac1n \text{Binomial}(n, X_t)$, where $n\in\N$. In other words, $X_t^n \in \{0, \frac1n, \ldots, \frac{n-1}n, 1\}$ for $t\geq 1$, and
$$\Pr\bp{X_{t+1}^n = \frac kn \mid X_t^n = p} = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}.$$
It's easy to see that $X_t^n$ is a martingale and it converges almost surely to either $0$ or $1$. Let $\tau_n = \min\{t\geq1 : X_t^n \in \{0, 1\}\}$ be the time until fixation. It's [known](http://www.genetics.org/content/61/3/763.full.pdf) that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \E\bp{\frac{\tau_n}n \mid X_0=x} = -2x\log x - 2(1-x)\log(1-x).$$
The proof of that formula requires using a diffusion approximation, which I find super hard to construct (it's done rigorously in [this book](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316658), for example). **Can you help me find an elementary proof?**

My idea is the following: let $f_n(x) := \E(\frac1n\tau_n|X_0=x)$. We have $f_n(x) = \frac1n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p_n(x,k) f_n(k/n)$ for $x\in[0,1]$, where $p_n(x,k) := \binom{n}{k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$. For each $n$, $f_n(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$, so we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^n p_n(x,k) \bp{f_n\bp{\frac kn} - f_n(x)} + \frac1n\bp{1 - p_n(x,0) - p_n(x,1)} = 0.$$
We can do a Taylor expansion
$$\sum_{k=0}^n p_n(x,k) \bp{f_n'(x)\bp{\frac kn - x} + \frac12 f_n''(x) \bp{\frac kn - x}^2 + \frac16 f_n'''(\xi_k) \bp{\frac kn - x}^3} + \frac1n\bp{1 - p_n(x,0) - p_n(x,1)} = 0.$$
We have $\sum_{k=0}^n p_n(x,k)\bp{\frac kn - x} = 0$, $\sum_{k=0}^n p_n(x,k) \bp{\frac kn - x}^2 = \frac1n x(1-x)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n p_n(x,k) \bp{\frac kn - x}^3 = \frac{1}{n^2} x(1-x)(1-2x)$, so replacing we get
$$\frac12 f_n''(x) x(1-x) = -1 + R_n(x),$$
where $|R_n(x)| \leq \frac1n \|f_n'''\|_\infty x(1-x)(1-2x) + p_n(x,0) + p_n(x,1)$.
If we can prove that $f_n, f_n', f_n'', f_n'''$ are all bounded we can pass to the limit, and we get the result. This doesn't sound so hard.

Comment: I think $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} p_n(x,k) f_n(k/n)$ should be $f_n(x) = \frac{p(x,0)+p(x,n)}{n}+\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} p_n(x,k) f_n(k/n) = \frac{(1-x)^n+x^n}{n}+\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} p_n(x,k) f_n(k/n)$

Comment: Further you have $F_n = P F_n$, You have to find the null space of $I-P$. $F_n = [f_n(0),f_n(1/n),....,f_n(1)]$ i.e., $(I-P)f = 0$

Comment: I saw the problem too late, took a look at the related Markov chain, which appears very natural, and to my surprise, the generator comes almost with a number theoretic  structure (well, maybe because it is determined by combinatorial means). This is a very good didactic example. I could find in the literature only proofs based on approximation by a diffusion process. The above idea to attack the asymptotics of $\Bbb E[\tau]$ still needs a lot of control for a fixed $n$ in the points $k/n$. This is the reason i could not make progress in this direction. Well, i've dropped a partial answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get a solution in the given framework, at some point one has to use in a clever manner the fact that we have a very specific Markov chain to work with.

I **do not have** and elementary solution so far, but below there
are some thoughts that may be useful in the context.
My hope is that the story can be converted in a proof not involving an approximation by continuous processes.

---

*Warming up:*

To see what happens in some very small case,
let us consider the toy case $N=7$.
We fix this $N$ and consider the Markov chain with states displayed (and identified) $k$ instead of $k/N$:

```
          4       4      7-4
         C  . p(1) . q(1)
          7
             .--.
           /      \
         /          \
       /             V
(x)----o----o----o----o----o----o----(x)
 0     1    2    3    4    5    6     7
```

and from each state but the extremal $0$, $7$
we can jump into any other state. Only one such jump was shown.
So if we are on the left side, the left side is the "preferred" side to jump
into.
The transition matrix is explicitly, just for fixing ideas:
$$
A 
= A(7)
=
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{279936}{823543} & \frac{46656}{117649} & \frac{23328}{117649} & \frac{6480}{117649} & \frac{1080}{117649} & \frac{108}{117649} & \frac{6}{117649} & \frac{1}{823543} \\
\frac{78125}{823543} & \frac{31250}{117649} & \frac{37500}{117649} & \frac{25000}{117649} & \frac{10000}{117649} & \frac{2400}{117649} & \frac{320}{117649} & \frac{128}{823543} \\
\frac{16384}{823543} & \frac{12288}{117649} & \frac{27648}{117649} & \frac{34560}{117649} & \frac{25920}{117649} & \frac{11664}{117649} & \frac{2916}{117649} & \frac{2187}{823543} \\
\frac{2187}{823543} & \frac{2916}{117649} & \frac{11664}{117649} & \frac{25920}{117649} & \frac{34560}{117649} & \frac{27648}{117649} & \frac{12288}{117649} & \frac{16384}{823543} \\
\frac{128}{823543} & \frac{320}{117649} & \frac{2400}{117649} & \frac{10000}{117649} & \frac{25000}{117649} & \frac{37500}{117649} & \frac{31250}{117649} & \frac{78125}{823543} \\
\frac{1}{823543} & \frac{6}{117649} & \frac{108}{117649} & \frac{1080}{117649} & \frac{6480}{117649} & \frac{23328}{117649} & \frac{46656}{117649} & \frac{279936}{823543} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Yes, this is a mess, but the eigenvalues are not,
they are in decreasing order:
$$
\boxed1\ ,\ \boxed1\ ,\ \frac{6}{7}\ ,\ \frac{30}{49}\ ,\ \frac{120}{343}\ ,\ \frac{360}{2401}\ ,\ \frac{720}{16807}\ ,\ \frac{720}{117649}
\ .
$$
And eliminating the boxed entries, these are:
$$
\frac 67\ ,\
\frac {6\cdot 5}{7^2}\ ,\
\frac {6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{7^3}\ ,\
\frac {6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{7^4}\ ,\
\frac {6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2}{7^5}\ ,\
\frac {6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{7^6}\ .
$$
Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix having these entries on the diagonal.
Let $S,T$ be base change matrices, inverse to each other, so that
$A$ diagonalizes as
$$
\tag{$\bbox[yellow]{1}$}
A=SDT\ ,
\qquad
D=
\begin{bmatrix}
\boxed 1\\
& \boxed 1\\
& & \frac{6}{7}\\
& & & \frac{30}{49}\\
& & & & \frac{120}{343}\\ 
& & & & & \frac{360}{2401}\\ 
& & & & & & \frac{720}{16807}\\
& & & & & & & \frac{720}{117649}
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
Denote by
$$
\tag{$\bbox[yellow]{2}$}
\Delta
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\bbox[lightblue]{\boxed 0}\\
& \bbox[lightblue]{\boxed 0}\\
& & \frac{6}{7}\\
& & & \frac{30}{49}\\
& & & & \frac{120}{343}\\ 
& & & & & \frac{360}{2401}\\ 
& & & & & & \frac{720}{16807}\\
& & & & & & & \frac{720}{117649}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the matrix obtained from $D$ by replacing the boxed
entries $\boxed 1$  by $\bbox[lightblue]{\text{zero}}$.
The denominators of the eigenvalues are powers of $7$. (It is the reason we took a prime $N$ to illustrate.)
The first two $\boxed1\ ,\ \boxed1$ eigenvalues correspond to the absorbant states $0$ and $N=7$. In fact, taking
(the left eigenvectors)
$w_0=(1,0,\dots,0)$ and $w_N=(0,0,\dots,0,1)$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
w_0A &=w_0\ ,\\
w_NA &=w_N\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Define similarly $w_k$ to be the row vector with $(N+1)=8$ entries,
all but one being zero, on the state position $k$ is this non-zero entry, and
it is $1$. For instance, $w_1=(0,1,0,\dots,0)$.

There is an obvious symmetry in the way the transition is done,
and  in fact we may identify in computations the states $k$, and $N-k$,
i.e. $x=k/N$ and its complement $1-x=(N-k)/N$.
(But not in genetics, where the difference counts.)
This is also the reason why the result
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\qquad
f(x) = -2x\log x-2(1-x)\log(1-x)
\qquad}
$$
shows the same symmetry.
But now it comes, let us start with
$w_1=(0,1,0,\dots,0)$ instead (of $w_0$, $w_N=w_7$), which corresponds to a starting point
$x=1/7$ for the process.
Which is the probability to land in $D=\{0,N\}$ before or in step $10$?
Numerically computing $w_1A^{10}$ delivers
$$
\scriptstyle
(\ 0.7874\dots\ ,\qquad 0.0223\dots\ ,\qquad  0.0247\dots\ ,\qquad 0.0244\dots\ ,\qquad  0.0234\dots\ ,\qquad  0.0217\dots\ ,\qquad  0.0182\dots\ ,\qquad  0.0774\dots\ )
$$
and this is an approximative list of probabilities to land after ten steps in $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$.
So starting in $1$ we land in either $0$ or $7$ with a high probability **in or before** step ten,
it is the sum of the extremal values,
$\approx 0.864916775\dots$ -- but we want a general expression.

Let now $\tau = \tau(N) = \tau(7)$ be the time of entrance in the final set of states
$D=\{0,N\}$. Let us compute its expectation, conditioned by the start in
one of the states $1,2,3,4,5,6$. The process is $X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots$ - and we omit here the upper index $N=7$, which is irritating for me.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb E[\ \tau \cdot 1_{\tau \le M}\ |\ X_0=k \ ]
&=
\sum_{1\le m\le M} m\cdot\Bbb P(\tau=m\ |\ X_0=k) 
\\
&=
\sum_{1\le m\le M} \Bbb P(m\le \tau\le M\ |\ X_0=k) 
\\
&=
\sum_{1\le m\le M} \Big(1-\Bbb P(\tau< m\ |\ X_0=k)\Big) 
\\
&=
M -
\sum_{m< M} \Bbb P(\tau< m\ |\ X_0=k) 
\\
&=
M - \sum_{m< M} w_k\cdot A^m\cdot (w_0+w_N)^T
\\
&=
M - \sum_{m< M} w_k\cdot S\; D^m\; T\cdot (w_0+w_N)^T
\\
&=
- \sum_{m< M} w_k\cdot S\; \Delta^m\; T\cdot (w_0+w_N)^T
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And now we can pass to the limit. We have the formula for the mean value of
$\tau=\tau(N=7)$, conditioned by the start in $k$:
$$
f_7(k/7) :=\Bbb E[\ \tau\ |\ X_0=k\ ]=w_k\ F(A(7))\ (w_0+w_7)^T\ ,
$$
where $F$ is the functional calculus for matrices implemented by the function
$$
F(\lambda)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac 1{1-\lambda} &\text{ for }\lambda \ne 1\ ,\\
 0 &\text{ for }\lambda = 1\ .
\end{cases}
$$
This allows us to compute explicitly (i did it with sage):
$$
\scriptstyle
\begin{aligned}
f_7(1/7) &=\frac 17\Bbb E\Big[\ \tau(7)\ \Big| X_0=\frac 17\ \Big]
=
\frac{2546425}{3587401} 
\approx 0.70982446623614\dots\ ,\
& f(1/7) &\approx 0.82023263657682\dots
\ ,\\
f_7(2/7) &=\frac 17\Bbb E\Big[\ \tau(7)\ \Big| X_0=\frac 27\ \Big]
=
\frac{3749893}{3587401} 
\approx 1.0452951872400\dots\ ,\
& f(2/7) &\approx 1.1965391771705\dots
\ ,\\
f_7(3/7) &=\frac 17\Bbb E\Big[\ \tau(7)\ \Big| X_0=\frac 37\ \Big]
=
\frac{4310467}{3587401}
\approx 1.2015570603900\dots\ ,\
& f(3/7) &\approx 1.3658162094009\dots
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and the next values come by central symmetry w.r.t $N/2$.
We are far away from a good approximation.
The above data in a table is:
$$
\scriptstyle
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|l|}
\hline 
k & f_7(k/7) & \approx & f(k/7)\\\hline\hline
1 & \frac{2546425}{3587401} & \approx 0.70982446623614 & 0.82023263657682\\\hline
2 & \frac{3749893}{3587401} & \approx 1.0452951872400 & 1.1965391771705\\\hline
3 & \frac{4310467}{3587401} & \approx 1.2015570603900 & 1.3658162094009\\\hline
4 & \frac{4310467}{3587401} & \approx 1.2015570603900 & 1.3658162094009\\\hline
5 & \frac{3749893}{3587401} & \approx 1.0452951872400 & 1.1965391771705\\\hline
6 & \frac{2546425}{3587401} & \approx 0.70982446623614 & 0.82023263657682\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Now i am trying to understand your way to proceed.
Above we have explicit values for $f_7(k/7)$ for $k=1,2,3,4,5,6$.
We do not know these values, they were obtained not so easy, and they will possibly incorporate for a huge $N$ (instead of $7$) the qualities of the function we need, the claimed $f$.

Now you build a polynomial $\tilde f_7$, that "interpolates somehow" around the true $f_7$, computed only in the points $k/7$. I am using a distinct notation for the polynomial you want to use.
But we do not have any control about values the interpolation points!
At some essential place in the argumentation we need the information on $A(7)$. And i do not see how to get it for $\tilde f_7$, without knowing
something real about the structure. I was really trying to understand the OP point of view, and to make similar ideas work, unfortunately with no success.

Explicitly, $\tilde f_7$ is given by the formula
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde f_7(x)
&=
\frac 17
+
\binom 71 (x^1(1-x)^6 + x^6(1-x)^1)\cdot f_7(1/7)
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
\binom 72 (x^2(1-x)^5 + x^5(1-x)^2)\cdot f_7(2/7)
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
+
\binom 73 (x^3(1-x)^4 + x^4(1-x)^3)\cdot f_7(3/7)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then indeed, $\tilde f_7$ reproduces the values in $k/7$ for $k=1,2,3,4,5,6$.
But it is "far away" from the final $f$, since:
$$
\tilde f_7(0) = \frac 17= \tilde f_7(1)\ .
$$
(This is not important for the step of bounding some first few derivatives of
$\tilde f_7$, but shows that $\tilde f_7$ differs from $f_7$ in $0$ and $1$.)

And now my counterquestion: How do you want to easily control
the values of interpolation in $k/7$, $k=1,2,3,4,5,6$, without making any usage of the data for the given Markov process? At some core point this input must show up. And it is the "combinatorial complexity" of the transition matrix $A(7)$ that rules the case $N=7$.

---

*Some more experimental data:*
The same experiment for a bigger value of $N$, say $N=20$ is as follows:
$$
\scriptstyle
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|l|}
\hline 
k & f_{20}(k/20) & \approx & f(k/20)\\\hline\hline
%
1 & \frac{7049188017677089148918383035074123555908980878133556724593594463258218383156940098323116366369}{6823789235596765144140629397025116769329495612742284464608652858407310928270219445149970976240} & \approx 0.36156096283229 & 0.39703048669174\\\hline
2 & \frac{2335814664092743620771139113457792637469879134230458597696621742955688645284519438410381117045}{1364757847119353028828125879405023353865899122548456892921730571681462185654043889029994195248} & \approx 0.59903310624523 & 0.65016594678290\\\hline
3 & \frac{3066866851137700430187978117403306202837994846657109853011948446724461100298583199265123415811}{1364757847119353028828125879405023353865899122548456892921730571681462185654043889029994195248} & \approx 0.78651564463532 & 0.84541817561198\\\hline
4 & \frac{11082195624050198044509776245729220461577721976957164252984248241915031612212168990733435588}{4140648808007745839891158614699706777505761900935852223670299064567543038998919566231778505} & \approx 0.93675379107648 & 1.0008048470764\\\hline
5 & \frac{8242352454110531301679729643769368646296120374656279626498263793099977510627523852061645098615}{2729515694238706057656251758810046707731798245096913785843461143362924371308087778059988390496} & \approx 1.0568993484917 & 1.1246702892376\\\hline
6 & \frac{22444958821943318833036770508497197960931017164921692885572709363738404636686839929695028046929}{6823789235596765144140629397025116769329495612742284464608652858407310928270219445149970976240} & \approx 1.1512277587209 & 1.2217286041098\\\hline
7 & \frac{9533245189029204917354883113933211804063813476242535247406674747794722799275789080450639972109}{2729515694238706057656251758810046707731798245096913785843461143362924371308087778059988390496} & \approx 1.2224277820432 & 1.2948932780693\\\hline
8 & \frac{310050519249895938543275899853764306860070874310658824806810900982118668951562345522587685054}{85297365444959564301757867462813959616618695159278555807608160730091386603377743064374637203} & \approx 1.2722278252250 & 1.3460233340185\\\hline
9 & \frac{204668169752762401897820253160959776770142211496912797141711476828487349284551071140420616811}{55030558351586815678553462879234812655883029135018423101682684341994442969921124557661056260} & \approx 1.3017105688044 & 1.3762776274272\\\hline
10 & \frac{5113842279229708841374847281282699449258692927812485655595027235115853099434657694262394715285}{1364757847119353028828125879405023353865899122548456892921730571681462185654043889029994195248} & \approx 1.3114742674008 & 1.3862943611199\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
And we are still far away from an approximation.

Note that the involved eigenvalues of the transition matrix are all rational, this happens all the time:
$$
\scriptstyle
1\ ,\ 
1\ ,\ 
\frac{19}{20}\ ,\ 
\frac{171}{200}\ ,\ 
\frac{2907}{4000}\ ,\ 
\frac{2907}{5000}\ ,\ 
\frac{8721}{20000}\ ,\ 
\frac{61047}{200000}\ ,\ 
\frac{793611}{4000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{2380833}{20000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{26189163}{400000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{26189163}{800000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{235702467}{16000000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{235702467}{40000000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{1649917269}{800000000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{4949751807}{8000000000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{4949751807}{32000000000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{4949751807}{160000000000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{14849255421}{3200000000000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{14849255421}{32000000000000000}\ ,\ 
\frac{14849255421}{640000000000000000}\ .
$$
They are explicitly, if we neglect the two $\boxed 1$ "absorbant" eigenvalues:
$$
\frac {19}{20}\ ,\
\frac {19\cdot 18}{20^2}\ ,\
\frac {19\cdot 18\cdot 17}{20^3}\ ,\
\frac {19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16}{20^4}\ ,\
\frac {19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 14}{20^5}\ ,\
\frac {19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 14\cdot 13}{20^6}\ , \ \dots\ 
$$
And for $N=40$ the table is, this time omitting the exact values:
$$
\scriptstyle
\begin{array}{|r|l|l|}
\hline 
k & f_{40}(k/40) & f(k/40)\\\hline\hline
%
1 & \approx 0.21673266441314 & 0.23381369827506\\\hline
2 & \approx 0.37223854481506 & 0.39703048669174\\\hline
3 & \approx 0.50406088185097 & 0.53276892653584\\\hline
4 & \approx 0.61875521092950 & 0.65016594678290\\\hline
5 & \approx 0.72004737593955 & 0.75354032251287\\\hline
6 & \approx 0.81024430522157 & 0.84541817561198\\\hline
7 & \approx 0.89088644809320 & 0.92745287963882\\\hline
8 & \approx 0.96306563545260 & 1.0008048470764\\\hline
9 & \approx 1.0275905471024 & 1.0663276814746\\\hline
10 & \approx 1.0850792979196 & 1.1246702892376\\\hline
11 & \approx 1.1360149118420 & 1.1763375547084\\\hline
12 & \approx 1.1807805433076 & 1.2217286041098\\\hline
13 & \approx 1.2196828831926 & 1.2611620567720\\\hline
14 & \approx 1.2529682563011 & 1.2948932780693\\\hline
15 & \approx 1.2808339711431 & 1.3231264763160\\\hline
16 & \approx 1.3034364540774 & 1.3460233340185\\\hline
17 & \approx 1.3208971213928 & 1.3637092174616\\\hline
18 & \approx 1.3333065992289 & 1.3762776274272\\\hline
19 & \approx 1.3407276869489 & 1.3837933184102\\\hline
20 & \approx 1.3431973194352 & 1.3862943611199\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
We take so far the message, that the error
$
\displaystyle \left|f_N\left(\frac kN\right)-f\left(\frac kN\right)\right|
$
is of the shape $1/N+$lower terms.
I am stopping here the experiments.

---

---

**An elementary solution?**

It seems that everybody uses the diffusion process approximation.
This is done in all references i found, first of all the time line $0,1,2,\dots,N$
is rescaled to fit in the interval $[0,1]$,
then the prcess is replaced by a continuous one
having the same distribution, and the same "main features" (mean, covariance,
independent increments, and so on), the continuous process is governed
by a generator, a differential operator appears, and we are searching for
solution(s) to a differential equation...

For the suggested path in the present question i have no continuation.

So i'll try to go (elementary) my way.

We fix an $N$. Things can be done in generality, but i will display formulas for $N=7$ again.
Recall that we have a matrix $A(7)$. It has on the positions pairs (corresponding to the states,
and the transition between them)
$(0,0)$ and $(N,N)=(7,7)$ an entry equal to one, which in fact leads to the
entries $\boxed 1$ in the spectrum (set of eigenvalues)
and so on the diagonal of the diagonal matrix $D$, realizing the diagonalization
$\bbox[yellow]{(1)}$. We want to get rid of these entries in $D$, thus passing from $D$ to $\Delta$.
It is enough to obtain a "partial diagonalization" (only for the data corresponding
to the $\boxed 1$ eigenvalues) in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \boxed1\\ & Q\\ &&\boxed1
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
We do this as follows. The column vectors with the entries $N,\dots2,1,0$ and $0,1,2,\dots,N$
are right eigenvectors for $A(N)=A(7)$. So we build the "partial Jordan form"
base change matrix:
$$
U = U(7) =
\begin{bmatrix}
  7   & & & & & & & 0 \\
  6 & 1 & & & & & & 1 \\
  5 & & 1 & & & & & 2 \\
  4 & & & 1 & & & & 3 \\
  3 & & & & 1 & & & 4 \\
  2 & & & & & 1 & & 5 \\
  1 & & & & & & 1 & 6 \\
  0 & & & & & & &   7
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  7 &   & 0 \\
  c & I & d \\
  0 &   & 7
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Denote by $V(7)$ the inverse of $U(7)$, here is a good point to introduce
it, (and forget about it for a while):
$$
V = V(7) =
\begin{bmatrix}
   1/7   & & & & & & & 0 \\
  -6/7 & 1 & & & & & & -1/7 \\
  -5/7 & & 1 & & & & & -2/7 \\
  -4/7 & & & 1 & & & & -3/7 \\
  -3/7 & & & & 1 & & & -4/7 \\
  -2/7 & & & & & 1 & & -5/7 \\
  -1/7 & & & & & & 1 & -6/7 \\
  0    & & & & & & &   1/7
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
We write $A(7)$ also in this block format $(1,6,1)\times(1,6,1)$,
with the $6\times 6$-matrix "in the middle" denoted by $Q$, and with left and right
neighbour $6\times 1$ vectors $a,b$.
And we multiply $A(7)\cdot U(7)$.
Since the first and the last columns of $U$ are right $1$-eigenvectors, they are kept in place.
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
  A(7)\cdot U(7)
  &=
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0\\
  a & Q & b\\
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
7 &   & 0 \\
c & I & d \\
0 &   & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
        =
        \begin{bmatrix}
          7 &   & 0 \\
          a & Q & b \\
          0 &   & 7
        \end{bmatrix}
                  =
\begin{bmatrix}
  7 &   & 0 \\
  c & I & d \\
  0 &   & 7
\end{bmatrix}
      \underbrace{
      \begin{bmatrix}
  \boxed 1 &    & \\
       & Q  & \\
       &    & \boxed 1
\end{bmatrix}}_{:=B(7)}
  \\
  &=U(7)\cdot B(7)
\ .
\end{aligned}
\ .
$$
The last equality defines the notation $B(7)$.

Now as explained at the beginning, we want to understand for each $k$ (with $0<k<N$) the "object":
$$
w_k\cdot F(A)\cdot (w_0+w_N)^T\ .
$$
Here, $F(A)$ is the functional calculus in $A$, which sends $1$-eigenvalues to $0$,
else each eigenvalue $\lambda$ to $1/(1-\lambda)$. In particular,
$F(Q)=(I-Q)^{-1}$.
So the information is inside $F(A) \cdot (w_0+w_N)^T$, which is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  F(A) \cdot (w_0+w_N)^T
  &=F(\ UBV\ ) \cdot (w_0+w_N)^T\\
  &=U\ F(B)\ V \cdot (w_0+w_N)^T\\
  &=U\ F\left(\ 
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \boxed 1 &    & \\
                 & Q  & \\
                 &    & \boxed 1
      \end{bmatrix}
              \right)\ V \cdot (w_0+w_N)^T\\
  &=U 
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \boxed 0 &    & \\
                 & (I-Q)^{-1}  & \\
                 &    & \boxed 0
      \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix}
        1/7 \\
        -\underline1\\
        1/7
      \end{bmatrix}
  \\
  &=U
      \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        -(I-Q)^{-1}\underline1\\
        0
      \end{bmatrix}
  \\
  &=
      \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        -(I-Q)^{-1}\underline1\\
        0
      \end{bmatrix}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Here,
$\underline1$ is the column vector with all $(N-1)=6$ components equal to one.

To obtain information on this "object", we do not need
to get the "full inverse" of $(I-Q)$,
it is enough to "solve a system" of the shape $(I-Q)\underline f=\underline 1$.
Which is arguably a much simpler task.
(Although the experimental data shows that we cannot expect a total simplification
and an immediate asymptotic insight.)

The right eigenvectors of $Q$ have a combinatorial description.
I was trying to get an approximation based on this information, but the problem is in the details.
I may come back, but for the moment have to stop here...

Comment: Great work! A comment on the OP: if I'm not mistaken, when using a diffusion to solve the problem the only thing you need to know about the structure is that the process is a martingale, the conditional variance is what it is, and the higher moments grow slowly enough with $N$. Using only that you get the equation I got, which passing to the limit gives you the answer. So intuitively that naïve approach should work. In other words, you don't need to know much more about the process. But yeah, I have no clue even how to prove that $E\tau(N) = O(N)$. It seems very intuitive, though.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H(x) = -x\log_2(x)-(1-x)\log_2(1-x)$.

Then $f_n(x) = \frac{P(x,0)+P(x,1)}{n} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} P(x,k) f_n(k/n)$

Hence we have $$f_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} P(x,k) f_n(k/n) = E\left(H\left(\frac{X^n_1}{n}\right)\right)$$

where we have substituted $f_n(y) = H(y)$.

Since we have, binomial coefficients, by central limit theorem for binomial coefficients, we have convergence in distribution to a gaussian random variable and since $0 \leq H(s) \leq 1$ bounded, we have convergence in expectation $E(H(Y_n)) \rightarrow E(H(Z_n)) \rightarrow H(x)$ after transforming $Y_n = \frac{X^n_1}{n} \rightarrow distribution \rightarrow Z_n = N(x,\frac{x(1-x)}{n})$ and hence the proof.

This just proves that given expression is one of the solutions.

For applying above, we need to extend $H(y) = 0$ for $y<0$ and $y>1$.

Comment: This wouldn't be enough to prove the convergence, because even if you prove that each term of the sum converges to what you want it to converge, the sum may not converge. If you can think how to use the dominated convergence theorem, that would be fantastic. Without something like that, i.e., a good enough uniform bound on the convergence of the terms, we are far from a proof.

Comment: Rewrote the entire answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Sorry, now I just don't understand the reasoning at all. Why do you substitute $f_n(y) = H(y)$? The whole point of the problem is to prove $f_n(y) \to H(y)$. You can't just assume that. What am I missing?

Comment: I proved that $f_n(y) = H(y)$ satisfies the recursion formula $f(x) = \sum_k P(x,k) f_n(k/n)$ you derived as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Hence i proved, based on your recursion you can get this solution. You need to add more constraints which will justify uniqueness of $f_n(x)$ if $f_n(x)$ satisfies all these constraints. I just derived the proof based on your recursion which is what i guess you were aiming for from your question. Atleast this is the limit of what you can do with your recursion formula.

Comment: You can see based on my derivation that your recursion formula will give any bounded continuous function $f(x)$ with support $0 \leq x \leq 1$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$ as solution. Try forming more equations which will guarantee unique solution and post it in the question.

Comment: After forming these uniqueness guaranteeing equations substitute $f(y)  = 2H(y) $ or $f(y) = H(y)$ and prove it satisfies the equations.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this helps to get to a full proof.